# what is used in jsp if in php using isset? like the example below

Tags: php, jsp

what is used in jsp if in php using isset? like the example below

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['pass'])){
?>
<a href="index.php?page=add_news"> <li class = "menu-li"> Write News </ li> </a>
<a href="index.php?page=orgz"> <li class = "menu-li"> Organize News </ li> </a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your question more exactly ? U.U

Comment: This is five seconds search.